# How to remove macros from binary MS Office documents?

Tags: macros, ms-office

How can I programmatically remove macros from binary Microsoft Office documents (`doc`, `xls`, `ppt`)?

I **do not want** to do it for the XML format (`xlsx`, `docx`, `pptx`).

I **do not** want to disable macros in office, I really want to modify the file(s) and strip them of any macros.

Answer (score 3):

This is assuming you want to automate the actual applications.

Add references to:

- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254954.aspx)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.aspx)
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint Microsoft Visual Basic for
  Applications Extensibility Library

The following should get rid of your macro code for Excel.  Automating Word and PowerPoint will be similar.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using PPT = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;

namespace OfficeMacros
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        static void RemoveMacrosExcel(string fileName, string newFileName)
        {
            var excel = new Excel.Application();
            var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            foreach (VBComponent component in workbook.VBProject.VBComponents)
            {
                switch (component.Type)
                {
                    case (vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule):
                    case (vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_MSForm):
                    case (vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ClassModule):
                        workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove(component);
                        break;
                    default:
                        component.CodeModule.DeleteLines(1, component.CodeModule.CountOfLines);
                        break;
                }
            }

            workbook.Close(true, newFileName, Type.Missing);

            // Release variables
            workbook = null;
            excel = null;

            // Collect garbage
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to parse the binary file structures yourself, you will need to review these documents:

- [[MS-DOC]: Word (.doc) Binary File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313153%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [[MS-XLS]: Excel Binary File Format (.xls) Structure Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313154%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [[MS-PPT]: PowerPoint (.ppt) Binary File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313106%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

If that seems too daunting, there is an excellent library created by [DIaLOGIKa](http://www.dialogika.de/) called [b2xtranslator](http://b2xtranslator.sourceforge.net/) (Binary(doc,xls,ppt) to OpenXMLTranslator).  It has most (if not all) of the binary structures for .doc, .xls, and .ppt mapped to C# objects.

While b2xtranslator's intention is to translate binary office documents to the newer OpenXML format, you could use the library to parse the documents and remove the macro elements yourself.

Comment: +1. So much simpler now; when I had to do this years ago (95/97 timeframe), Microsoft required signing a non-disclosure agreement to get the binary format document :-)